# Using select2 With MVC model binding

Tags: jquery, asp.net-core-mvc, jquery-select2

Im using two Select2 with MVC model binding.

one have List value from model and second one grabs value

with Ajax from condition of first one.

Chtml :

```
<select asp-for=select2firstdropdown tabindex="19">
@foreach (DataRow item in (ViewData["listone_obj"] as DataTable).Rows)
       {
         <option value="@item["ListID"]" selected>@item["ListTitle"]</option>
       }
</select>

<select asp-for=select2seconddropdown  tabindex="19"></select>
```

and js :

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $("#select2firstdropdown").select2();


    $("#select2seconddropdown").select2({
        language: "fa",
        ajax: {
            url: "/Contraoller/Getlistforseconddorpdown",
            dataType: 'json',
            delay: 250,
            data: function (params) {
                return {
                    searchterm: params.term, // search term
                    publicationid: $("#select2firstdropdown").val(),
                    page: params.page
                };
            },
            processResults: function (data, params) {
                params.page = params.page || 1;
                var o = JSON.parse(data);
                return {
                    results: $.map(o, function (item) {
                        return {
                            text: item.title,
                            id: item.id
                        }
                    }),
                    pagination: {
                        more: (params.page * 30) < data.total_count
                    }
                };
            },
            cache: true
        },
        escapeMarkup: function (markup) { return markup; },
        minimumInputLength: 0
    });


$("#select2firstdropdown").val(select2firstdropdownselectedID);

$("#select2seconddropdown").val(select2seconddropdownselectedID).trigger("change");
}
```

now if i open view with model result , first selec2 dropdown shows selected value but second one is empty.

Comment: What is the version of `select2` you are using?

Comment: Im using latest version "Select2 4.0.2" from bower

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not initializing your second dropdown with any options, so there is no `option` element to get selected from the value

Comment: Thanks for answer , tried that but still nothing happend.